# Closing a file and writing to it via a mem-map valid?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, memory-mapped-files

I came across something I've never seen before in the Linux `pthreads` documentation here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_init

What I'm referring to is the below:

```
int fd = open(....);
void* ptr = mmap(....);
close (fd);
return ptr;
```

How can `ptr` still be valid if the file is closed? I was under the impression that the file has to be open throughout the life-time of the map. Then when you are ready to destroy it, you `munmap` first THEN you `close`..

Can someone explain why this code is valid? Does this also hold true for windows?

Comment: Why should memory mapping a file be connected to having a stream connected to it? That said, it is the same under MS Windows, though it used to be different under early versions of MS Windows CE.

Comment: File handles in Linux are reference-counted, so the file doesn't need to be kept open (or rather, `mmap` will ensure it stays open!)